# Android SQLiteDatabase query may produce NPE

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-studio

Just trying to understand why:

```
    db = databaseHandler.getReadableDatabase();

    String[] columns = {ID, NAME, DIFFICULTY};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, DIFFICULTY);
```

The uppercase variables in the above snippet are obviously static finals.
Android studio is telling me

"This inspection reports those conditions in the specified inspection scope that are always true or false, as well as points out where a RuntimeException may be thrown, based on data flow analysis of the code. This inspection also reports Nullable/NotNull contract violations. Annotations to support the contract can be configured (by default @Nullable/@NotNull annotations from annotations.jar will be used)"

This is gibberish to me. Can someone explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That tool tries to help you to find places where errors are likely to happen.
In this particular case, it complains about every place where you are using `null` and where it is not able to prove that this usage is allowed.

However, the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) shows that `null` values are indeed allowed for these parameters, so that tool is just wrong.
Furthermore, `SQLiteDatabase`'s `query` method is part of the Android API, so there is no excuse. Consider this a bug in the inspector.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's kind of what I was thinking but didn't want to make a noob-level assumption.